# Don't see Crash in console

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I add FireBase to my android app.
I add step by step complete FireBase and analytics SDK to app.
But,
I see and work analytics parameters in console except Crashlytics.

in below , I put my codes and my dependencies

My dependencies and codes:

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.1' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.1' apply false
id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.15' apply false
id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics' version '2.9.5' apply false  }
```

,

```
ependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.1.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
//implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
//  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'}
```

,

Setting :

```
 pluginManagement {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
}
}
 dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
}
rootProject.name = "fireBaseTesting"
include ':app'
```

,

MyCodes:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);

    Button crashButton = new Button(this);
    crashButton.setText("Test Crash");
    crashButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Test Crash"); // Force a crash
        }
    });

    addContentView(crashButton, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

  }
  }
```

also my java is 17 and Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2

and in my log firebase crashlytics enabled is false